# How to get Ajax returns an array with objects with multiple values and append to HTML

Tags: javascript, ajax, response

I am trying to get a response with multiple arrays and pass to view so users can click on it and make request to another endpoint.

The response has value and text.

```
  <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="text-center">
                <h3>Get Prices</h3>
                <hr>
                <h3>Price 1</h3>
                <p id="price1"></p>

                <hr>
                <h3>Price 2</h3>
                <p id="price1"></p>

                <hr>
                <h3>Price 3</h3>
                <p id="price1"></p>

                <hr>
                <h3>Price 4</h3>
                <p id="price1"></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
         //http://datarecapture.premiumpension.com:8089/api/Prices/GetAllFundNames


        $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({  
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://datarecapture.premiumpension.com:8089/api/Prices/GetAllFundNames',
            contentType: "application/json",

            success: function(results) {
               console.log(results)
               for(var i=0; i< results.length; i++)
                {
                $('#price1').append()
                {
                    value: result[i].FUND_ID[0]
                    Text: result[i].FUND_NAME[0]
                }
                $('#price2').append()
                {
                    value: result[i].FUND_ID[1]
                    Text: result[i].FUND_NAME[2]
                }

                $('#price3').append()
                {
                    value: result[i].FUND_ID[2]
                    Text: result[i].FUND_NAME[2]
                }

                }

        //$('ul#response').html(results);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error){

        debugger
         var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
         alert('Error - ' + errorMessage);}
    });

  });
```

Comment: You are getting multiple array or object

Comment: What does #price1 refer to?

Comment: This is what I am getting 'result: Array(4)
0: {FUND_ID: 13, FUND_NAME: "RSA Fund I"}
1: {FUND_ID: 1, FUND_NAME: "RSA Fund II"}
2: {FUND_ID: 14, FUND_NAME: "RSA Fund III"}
3: {FUND_ID: 2, FUND_NAME: "RSA Fund IV"}'

Comment: #price1 is the id of the paragraph I want to append the value and name.  <p id="price1"></p>

Comment: So you want the FUND_NAME as a text in the paragraph element?

Comment: You should refer to [this](https://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: Fund 1, Fund 2, Fund 3 etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199440/discussion-between-techstack-and-aakash-choubey).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it with this

```
              for (var i = 0; i < resp.result.length; i++) {
                console.log('hello: results', JSON.stringify(resp.result[i].FUND_NAME));


                $('.funds-item-container').append(
                   `<div><h5>Price ${i+1}</h5>
                      <a id='#price${i+1}'>
                       <a href="${resp.result[i].FUND_ID}"> ${resp.result[i].FUND_NAME}</a>
                      </p>
                    </div><hr>`
                );
              }
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to append an entry with the id and the name of each fund in each section.

If I'm correct, change your `for-loop` into the following:

```
for(var i=0; i< results.length; i++){
    $('#price'+(i+1)).append('<p class="id">'+results[i].FUND_ID+'</p><p class="name">'+results[i].FUND_NAME+'</p>');
}
```

Provided you have hardcoded the correct length into the entries, this does the following:
it starts looping through all your price id tags (to start with `#price1`, instead of `#price0` I added the +1) and adds to each two p tags, the first with the `FUND_ID` and then with `FUND_NAME`.
You can play around with those to have them show up the way you like.

I would also suggest to remove the hard coded `h3` and `p` tags and add them inside the Ajax call as well.

Comment: for reasons I dont understand. `console.log(results[i].FUND_ID);` is not working

Comment: try `results[i]['FUND_ID']`. If it doesn't work, can you provide the output of `console.log(results[i])`?